# What can cause IDXGISwapChain2's frame latency waitable to timeout?

Tags: directx-11, directx-12, dxgi

What can cause `IDXGISwapChain2`'s frame latency waitable to timeout?

I'm trying to implement this recommendation from Microsoft: [Reduce latency with DXGI 1.3 swap chains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/reduce-latency-with-dxgi-1-3-swap-chains), but this code here from the article:

```
  DWORD result = WaitForSingleObjectEx(
        m_frameLatencyWaitableObject,
        1000, // 1 second timeout (shouldn't ever occur)
        true
        );
```

*sometimes* (not always) returns WAIT_TIMEOUT although the article says it shouldn't ever occur. I probably do something I shouldn't, but what can cause this waitable to timeout?

Comment: Maybe you are recreating swap chain and `frameLatencyWaitableObject` is not a current object anymore?

Comment: I think the comment should read "should not occur under normal conditions". If the system is heavily loaded, such as with 100% CPU utilization or intensive swap file activity w/ low free memory conditions, this particular waiting thread might get its execution time delayed for a second.

Comment: I've checked and the waitable is still valid (I don't recreate the swapchain, I just resize buffers when the window is resized). And, no, the system (cpu, gpu, memory) is not under heavy load at all.

Comment: Is this during resize of buffers?

Comment: @RomanR - not particularly. Actually, I'm wondering if the waitable doesn't require the Present (or Present1) to be called before. I though the waitable was like a timer, but it may just wait on the swapchain Present call...